# Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Location must equal europe-west1 because the App Engine app that is associated with this project is located in europe-west1

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I've written a functions in `Firestore Functions` which uses `Google Cloud Tasks` to trigger another function in the future. The problem with it is that it throws the following error:

> Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Location must equal europe-west1 because the App Engine app that is associated with this project is located in europe-west1

What I've tried is changing the functions location to `europe-west1` as it says, but I still get the same error. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it was a bug or something, but updating these fixed the problem:

`npm install -g firebase-tools@latest`

In functions directory:

`npm install firebase-functions@latest --save`

`npm install firebase-admin@latest --save-exact`

Comment: didn't seem to fix my issue :/ but I changed it from the function itself `functions.region('my-region').pubsub...`